# SciPy Can't Convert Complex to Float

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror

I am stuck at a problem, which I have simplified below.

So, I have a function (matrix) which returns eigenvalues of a matrix.

Second function (deriv) finds the derivatives of eigenvalues with respect to delta. SciPy's own derivative function is very slow, so I have used complex difference method.

Then I take the double integral of integrand over r and theta. Instead of taking the double integral, I solve a differential equation of r, after taking one dimensional integral over theta, which makes the calculations faster.

Finally, integral works. However, if I try to find the specific delta which satisfies the equation, it gives an error: Can't convert complex to float, which I don't understand where the imaginary number comes from.

I am new to Python world, any help would be quite appreciated. Thank you.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from numpy import linalg as LA
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.integrate import ode
from scipy.optimize import fsolve


#This routine is for the matrix and returns the eigenvalues
def matrix(r, theta, delta1, delta2):

    mat = np.array([[r**2-1,r*np.cos(theta),0,delta1],r*np.cos(theta),r**2 - 1, -delta1,0],[0,-delta2,-r**2+1,-r*np.cos(theta)],[delta2,0,-r*np.cos(theta),-r**2+1]])
    return np.sort(LA.eigvals(mat))[2:4]

#This routine takes the derivatives of eigenvalues with respect to the parameter delta. I set delta1 = delta2.
def deriv(r, theta, delta):

    h = 0.00000000001

    return np.imag(matrix(r, theta, delta, delta+h*1j))/h

#This is the integrand that we need to integrate over r and theta
def integrand(theta,r, beta, delta):
    ee = matrix(r, theta, delta, delta)
    dd = deriv(r, theta, delta)
    return (np.tanh(0.5*beta*ee[0])*dd[0]+np.tanh(0.5*beta*ee[1])*dd[1])*r*r*np.sin(theta)

#Just integrate over theta
def polarint(y,r,beta,delta):
    return quad(integrand,0,np.pi,args = (r,beta,delta))[0]

#Instead of integrating directly over r, solve the differential equation.
#Lambda is the range of r.
def givesclen(delta, beta, lam):
    y0 = 0
    t_out = np.linspace(0, lam, 2500);
    rt = odeint(polarint,y0,t_out,args=(beta,delta))
    temp = (rt[-1]/delta)/(4*np.pi**2)-t_out[-1]/(2*np.pi**2)
    return temp[0]

#The goal is to find the delta; given sl, lam, beta
#Such that the result of the integration is equal to sl
def equationgap(delta, beta, lam,sl):
    return givesclen(delta, beta, lam)*4*np.pi - sl

#Test if the equationgap works, the result should be close to zero!
print equationgap(.5,40,500,.1744)

#Now use the fsolve function should find the delta to be .5!
#beta = 40
#lam = 500
#sl = 0.174
#fsolve(equationgap,.6,args = (beta, lam, sl))
```

Edit:

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 38, in polarint
return quad(integrand,0,np.pi,args = (r,beta,delta))[0]
File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 281, in quad
retval = _quad(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit,points)
File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 345, in _quad
return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
File "test.py", line 30, in integrand
dd = deriv(r, theta, delta)
File "test.py", line 22, in deriv
return np.imag(matrix(r, theta, delta, delta+h*1j))/h
File "test.py", line 14, in matrix
mat = np.array([[r**2-1,r*np.cos(theta),0,delta1],[r*np.cos(theta),r**2 - 1, -delta1,0],[0,-delta2,-r**2+1,-r*np.cos(theta)],[delta2,0,-r*np.cos(theta),-r**2+1]])
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

Comment: Your call to `np.imag` is converting to complex.  Why is that in there?

Comment: It is for taking the derivative, taken from here: http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2013/10/14/complex-step-differentiation/

Comment: There are lots of derivative routines in python.  Are you mixing matlab code?  Anyway, np.imag means take the imaginary party.  If you call that function, it's going to convert its argument into a complex function.  I don't know what kind of derivative it's supposed to be.

Comment: It is the first derivative. The first explanation on the internet for this method to take first derivative was this link. I am trying to take the double integral of the function integrand. I have used SciPy derivative function to take derivative, but the integration was extremely slow. So I used this derivative function. How can I convert this to real number?

Comment: How bout just drop the np.imag part.  return matrix(... instead of return np.imag(matrix(...

Comment: That does not return the derivative to me. The trick to find derivative here is: F(x + ih) = F(x) + ih * F'(x) - Taylor Series. So in order to find the derivative, I can just take the imaginary part of the F(x + ih), then divide by h. This is much more faster and accurate. For usual finite difference method, decreasing the h might result in round-off error. Here in complex difference method, decreasing h yields more accurate result. If there is much better method to take derivative on Python, please let me know, as I am new to Python.

Comment: The result of the `matrix()` call is complex because `delta2` is imaginary.  `np.imag()` takes the imaginary part of that matrix, returning a real.  If `matrix()` was real, `np.imag` would return `0`.

Comment: Where is the `Can't convert complex to float` error occurring?  The stack trace should tell you.  We can't guess from just looking at your code.

Comment: Yes, but why the fsolve does not work while there is no problem for the function of the integral? Integral returns a real number, so there is no problem for that. But it gives error of "Can't convert complex to float" when I call that function from fsolve...

Comment: @hpaulj, When you run this python code, there is no problem. It returns a number. But, when I comment out the lines:
`beta = 40
lam = 500
sl = 0.174
fsolve(equationgap,.6,args = (beta, lam, sl))`
It gives `Can't convert complex to float` error.

Comment: @hpaulj, I have added the error message to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the minimal code that fails

```
from numpy import array
q = [[-1.0, 0.0, 0, array([ 0.6])], [0.0, -1.0, array([-0.6]), 0], [0, array([-0.6 -1.00000000e-11j]), 1.0, -0.0], [array([ 0.6 +1.00000000e-11j]), 0, -0.0, 1.0]]
array(q)
```

which is sort of strange. However, note that there are arrays with one element mixed in with the plain numbers there. This can be discovered just by printing out the object you give to `array()` before giving it.

To fix it, change delta to delta[0] in the function you give to fsolve:

```
def equationgap(delta, beta, lam,sl):
    return givesclen(delta[0], beta, lam)*4*np.pi - sl
```

because the rest of the code expects that delta is a single number, not an array. fsolve will give the function to be optimized an array of numbers, even if there is only a single one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, it did not solve the problem. Then, I have changed the part to `return givesclen(np.real(delta), beta, lam)*4*np.pi - sl` but again did not help.

Comment: The above change certainly makes the error you see above go away, if you make it in the code you have included above. Your own code then probably is different from what you have written above, but the cause of the error is very likely the same, so you should try to adapt the solution yourself. (Changing it to `np.real(delta)` will not change anything, because it is still an array.)

Comment: Thank you. Later on, I wrote my own routines to find the roots of the functions and it works. It's funny that I have been trying to make fsolve work for two weeks, and I wrote my own working code which does the same thing as fsolve in 2 hours :-) I should have started with writing my own code from the beginning.

Comment: You probably should have tried first using fsolve for simpler problems, and to learn how it is used and what do the inputs to the functions mean. Then more complex problems would have been easier to understand.

Comment: I had tried using fsolve before asking my question here, as well as tried for different simple cases and it had worked. It didn't work for my real case.

Answer (score 0):

I can produce your error message with:

```
x = np.ones((3,))
x[1] = 1 + 1j
```

`x` is a `dtype=float` array. Trying to insert a complex value produces the error.

If the error is produced in evaluating:

```
mat = np.array([[r**2-1,r*np.cos(theta),0,delta1],
                [r*np.cos(theta),r**2 - 1, -delta1,0],
                [0,-delta2,-r**2+1,-r*np.cos(theta)],
                [delta2,0,-r*np.cos(theta),-r**2+1]])
```

the question is - what values of `r`, `theta`, `delta1`, `delta2` can produce this error.   With 1st 3 being real scalars, and last complex, I get a `(4,4)` complex array.  I suspect one of these variables is something we don't expact.

---

I can shortend `pv`s minimal example to:

```
np.array([1, np.array([1j])])   # error
np.array([[1],np.array([1j])])  # ok
```

Switch the order of the terms, and result is different:

```
np.array([np.array([1j]),1])
# array([array([ 0.+1.j]), 1], dtype=object)
```

Evidently the error is the result of trying to build a larger array from a mix of scalar(s) and arrays, one of which is complex.  The error message is obscure, and probably the result of an unanticipated problem.  It may be worthy of a bug report.

And the solution is to either convert all those `0`s to lists `[0]`, or make sure that the `delta2` value is a scalar, not an array.

Comment: Thank you. Later on, I wrote my own routines to find the roots of the functions and it works. It's funny that I have been trying to make fsolve work for two weeks, and I wrote my own working code which does the same thing as fsolve in 2 hours :-) I should have started with writing my own code from the beginning.